# TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined issue while doing unit test in angular 5

Tags: angular5, karma-jasmine

I am trying to do unit test on my angular5 application.Each time when I type the 'ng test' command it shows some errors and I solve it.But now it returns a new error.

```
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Linux 0.0.0) ChannelsComponent should create FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
        at new ChannelsComponent src/app/rcyc-components/rcyc-channels/rcyc-channels.component.ts:71:53)
```

I am using activatedRoute in my component for retreiving the current url

```
this.currentUrlPathAsArray= this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url;       
this.currentUrlKey= this.currentUrlPathAsArray[0].path;
```

in the above code using the path property of activated route I am storing the current url.when doing unit test on my app  it retuns  'path' of undefined error.

**spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { ChannelsComponent } from './rcyc-channels.component';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { NgxCarouselModule } from "ngx-carousel";
import { RcycDecodeHtmlPipe } from '../../rcyc-pipes/rcyc-decode-html/rcyc-decode-html.pipe';
import { RcycLimitPipe } from "../../rcyc-pipes/rcyc-limit/rcyc-limit.pipe";
import { RcycDefaultImagePipe } from '../../rcyc-pipes/rcyc-default-image/rcyc-default-image.pipe';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { RcycCommonService } from '../../rcyc-services/rcyc-common/rcyc-common.service';
import { RcycChannelsService } from "./rcyc-channels.service";
describe('ChannelsComponent', () => {
  let component: ChannelsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChannelsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[RouterModule,NgxCarouselModule,HttpClientModule,RouterTestingModule],
      declarations: [ ChannelsComponent,RcycDecodeHtmlPipe,RcycLimitPipe,RcycDefaultImagePipe ],
      schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers:[RcycCommonService,RcycChannelsService]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChannelsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from "@angular/core";
// import { NgxCarousel , NgxCarouselStore} from "ngx-carousel";
import { Router, NavigationEnd, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { RcycChannelsService } from "./rcyc-channels.service";
import { AppConfig } from "../../rcyc-config/config";
import { RcycCommonService } from '../../rcyc-services/rcyc-common/rcyc-common.service';
import { NguCarousel,NguCarouselStore } from '@ngu/carousel';

@Component({
  selector: "app-channels",
  templateUrl: "./rcyc-channels.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./rcyc-channels.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [RcycChannelsService]
})
export class ChannelsComponent implements OnInit {

  public carouselOne: NguCarousel;
  deckTabObject: any;

  API_BASE_URL: any =   AppConfig.API_BASE_URL;
    IMG_BASE_URL: any =   AppConfig.IMG_BASE_URL;
    ELASTIC_API_BASE_URL: any =   AppConfig.ELASTIC_API_BASE_URL;

  tabcontent: any;
  basepath: any;
  apiResponseA: any;
  apiResponseB: any;
  apiResponseC: any;
  apiResponseD: any;
  apiResponseE: any;

  apiResponseATemp: any=[];
  apiResponseBTemp: any=[];
  apiResponseCTemp: any=[];
  apiResponseDTemp: any=[];
  apiResponseETemp: any=[];

  apiResponseAStatus: any = false;
  apiResponseBStatus: any = false;
  apiResponseCStatus: any = false;
  apiResponseDStatus: any = false;
  apiResponseEStatus: any = false;

  apiUrlA: any;
  apiUrlB: any;
  apiUrlC: any;
  apiUrlD: any;
  apiUrlE: any;
  apiUrlMetatag: any;

  currentUrlPathAsArray: any;
  currentUrlKey: any;
  currentComponentName: any;
  currentSlide:number = 0;

  constructor(

    private router: Router,
    private rcycChannelsService: RcycChannelsService,
    private rcycCommonService: RcycCommonService, 
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,   
  ) {

        // this.currentComponentName =  this.activatedRoute.routeConfig.component.name;                     
        this.currentComponentName = "RcycChannelsComponent";                        
        // Current subHeader Status
        this.rcycCommonService.changeSubHeaderStatus(true);

        this.currentUrlPathAsArray= this.activatedRoute.snapshot.url;       
        this.currentUrlKey= this.currentUrlPathAsArray[0].path;

        // To scroll up page
        this.router.events.subscribe(evt => {
      if (!(evt instanceof NavigationEnd)) {
        return;
      }
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });

        var switchKey= this.currentUrlKey;
        switch(switchKey) {

            case "cruise-ports":

                    // change changeCurrentComponent
                    this.rcycCommonService.changeCurrentComponent(this.currentComponentName);

                    // Call get Metatag function 
                    this.apiUrlMetatag= "/api/v1/meta/destinations?_format=json";
                    this.rcycCommonService.getMetaTags(this.apiUrlMetatag);

                    this.rcycDestinationsContent();
            break;

            case "experience":

                    // Call get Metatag function 
                    this.apiUrlMetatag= "/api/v1/meta/experience?_format=json";
                    this.rcycCommonService.getMetaTags(this.apiUrlMetatag);

                    this.rcycExperienceContent();
            break;

            case "presailing":

                    // Call get Metatag function 
                    this.apiUrlMetatag= "/api/v1/meta/presailing?_format=json";
                    this.rcycCommonService.getMetaTags(this.apiUrlMetatag);

                    this.rcycPresailingContent();           
            break;

            default:

            break;

        }
    }

  ngOnInit() {

        // split url and redirection
    /*if(this.currentUrlKey == "cruise-ports") {

            this.rcycDestinationsContent();
        } else {

            this.rcycExperienceContent();
        }*/
        //Carousel settings
    this.carouselOne = {
      grid: { xs: 1, sm: 1, md: 1, lg: 1, all: 0 },
      slide: 1,
      speed: 500,
      interval: 300000,
      point: {
        visible: false
      },
      load: 3,
      touch: true,
      loop: true,
      custom: "banner"
    };

    //Tab options
    this.deckTabObject = [
      {
        name: "Onboard",
        class: "tab-link tab-link_suites is-active",
        contentClass: "tab-pane is-visible",
        active: true
      },
      {
        name: "Ashore",
        class: "tab-link",
        contentClass: "tab-pane",
        active: false
      }
    ];

  }

/* =============================================================================================================================================
        Function to display Full Api Urls of Destination 
 =============================================================================================================================================== */
  rcycDestinationsContent() {

    this.apiUrlA = "/api/v1/destinations/header/a?_format=json";
    this.apiUrlB = "/api/v1/destinations/content/b?_format=json";
    this.apiUrlC = "/api/v1/destinations/content/c?_format=json";
    this.apiUrlD = "/api/v1/regions?_format=json";    

    this.rcycChannelContent();

  }

/* =============================================================================================================================================
        Function to display Full Api Urls of Experience 
 =============================================================================================================================================== */
  rcycExperienceContent() {

        this.apiUrlA = "/api/v1/experience/header/a?_format=json";
        this.apiUrlB = "/api/v1/experience/content/b?_format=json";
    this.apiUrlC = "/api/v1/experience/content/c?_format=json";    
    this.apiUrlD = "/api/v1/experience/content/d?_format=json";

    this.rcycChannelContent();

  }

/* =============================================================================================================================================
        Function to display Full Api Urls of Presailing 
 =============================================================================================================================================== */
  rcycPresailingContent() {

        this.apiUrlA = "/api/v1/presailing/header/a?_format=json";
        this.apiUrlB = "/api/v1/presailing/content/b?_format=json";
    this.apiUrlC = "/api/v1/presailing/content/c?_format=json";    
    this.apiUrlD = "/api/v1/presailing/content/d?_format=json";

    this.rcycChannelContent();

  }

/* =============================================================================================================================================
        Function to display Full Apis Channels 
 =============================================================================================================================================== */
  rcycChannelContent() {

        /****************** Section A********************/

    this.rcycChannelsService.channels(this.apiUrlA).subscribe(
      response => {

                this.apiResponseATemp = response;
                if(this.apiResponseATemp.length) {

                    // var res= Object.values(response);
                    var res= Object.keys(response).map(function(key) {
                                                return response[key];
                                        });
                    if(res.length) {

                        this.apiResponseAStatus = true;
                        this.apiResponseA = response[0];

                        // Changing subheader A value
                        this.rcycCommonService.changeSubHeaderDataArray_A(this.apiResponseA);

                    } else {

                        // Changing subheader A value
                        this.rcycCommonService.changeSubHeaderDataArray_A([]);                      
                    }   
                } else {

                    // Changing subheader A value
                    this.rcycCommonService.changeSubHeaderDataArray_A([]);                      
                }   

            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );


    /******************Header  Section B********************/

        this.rcycChannelsService.channels(this.apiUrlB).subscribe(
      response => {

                this.apiResponseBTemp = response;
                if(this.apiResponseBTemp.length) {

                    // var res= Object.values(response);    
                    var res= Object.keys(response).map(function(key) {
                                                return response[key];
                                        });
                    if(res.length) {

                        var resArray=[];
                        for(let index in res) {

                            var factor= res[index];
                            if(factor.field_image) {

                                factor.field_image= this.IMG_BASE_URL+factor.field_image;

                                let imgTitle= this.rcycCommonService.imageNameAltSplit(factor.field_image);

                                factor.altTextBannerImg= factor.title+ " "+ imgTitle;
                                factor.titleTextBannerImg= factor.title+ " "+ imgTitle;
                            }else {

                                factor.altTextBannerImg= factor.title;
                                factor.titleTextBannerImg= factor.title;
                            }
                            resArray.push(factor);
                            if( parseInt(index)+1 == res.length ) {

                                this.apiResponseBStatus = true;
                                this.apiResponseB = resArray;

                            }
                        }                       
                    }
                }
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

    /****************** Section C********************/

    this.rcycChannelsService.channels(this.apiUrlC).subscribe(
      response => {

                this.apiResponseCTemp = response;
                if(this.apiResponseCTemp.length) {

                    // var res= Object.values(response);
                    var res= Object.keys(response).map(function(key) {
                                                return response[key];
                                        });
                    if(res.length) {

                        this.apiResponseCStatus = true;
                        this.apiResponseC = response[0];
                    }
                }

      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );

    /****************** Section D********************/

    this.rcycChannelsService.channels(this.apiUrlD).subscribe(
      response => {

                this.apiResponseDTemp = response;
                if(this.apiResponseDTemp.length) {

                    // var res= Object.values(response);
                    var res= Object.keys(response).map(function(key) {
                                            return response[key];
                                    });
                    if(res.length) {

                        var resArray= [];
                        for(let index in res) {

                            var factor= res[index];

                            if(factor.field_image) {

                                factor.field_image= this.IMG_BASE_URL+factor.field_image;

                                let imgTitle= this.rcycCommonService.imageNameAltSplit(factor.field_image);

                                factor.altTextOnBoardImg= factor.title+ " "+ imgTitle;
                                factor.titleTextOnBoardImg= factor.title+ " "+ imgTitle;
                            }else {

                                factor.altTextOnBoardImg= factor.title;
                                factor.titleTextOnBoardImg= factor.title;
                            }

                            if(this.currentUrlKey == 'cruise-ports') {

                                let field_group_url_keyNew= factor.field_group_url_key.toLowerCase();
                                factor.channelUrl="/luxury-"+field_group_url_keyNew+"-cruises";
                            } else if(this.currentUrlKey == 'experience') {

                                let field_url_keyNew= factor.field_url_key.toLowerCase();
                                factor.channelUrl="/experience/"+field_url_keyNew;
                            }


                            resArray.push(factor);                              
                            if( parseInt(index)+1 == res.length ) {

                                this.apiResponseDStatus = true;                         
                                this.apiResponseD = resArray;                                                           
                            }
                        }       

                    }
                } 

      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );



  }

  // Function on Learn more click
  learnMoreClick(event, item) {
        /****************** Section E********************/


    }


    nextCarouselload(ev) {
    // console.log(ev);
  }


   onmoveFn(data: NguCarouselStore) {
    this.currentSlide = data.currentSlide;
  }

  clickFn(data: NguCarouselStore){
this.currentSlide = data.currentSlide-1;
  }
}
```

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: It's a definite red flag to be importing `HttpClientModule` into a component test, because: 1. components shouldn't make requests directly; and 2. tests shouldn't make real requests. It also seems weird to have the real and test router modules imported, and neither calling the appropriate static methods. Beyond that, please provide a [mcve] of component and test.

Comment: Note the M in MCVE...